# Concatenate 2 Singly-linked list

Tags: data-structures, singly-linked-list

I Wanna Concatenate 2 Singly Linked List with Ordered into one linked list.Each lists nude have a score value. And ı wanna order and concatenate 2 list.

```
SinglyLinkedList* conList = list1->concatLists(list2);


SinglyLinkedList* SinglyLinkedList::concatLists(SinglyLinkedList* list2)
```

{

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk through your first list and get the very final node and set the next node to the second node.

```
SinglyLinkedList* n = list1;
while(n->next != null){
    n = n->next;
}
n->next = list2
```